# Importing a module as an object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Let's imagine I have two files

```
# foo.py
a = 5
```

and

```
#bar.py
def call_foo():
    import foo
    foo.a += 1
    print(foo.a)

call_foo() # Prints 6
call_foo() # Prints 7
```

I would like to have, every time I call `call_foo()`, 6 to be printed.

In other words, `import foo` should act like creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the module *globals* locally avoiding the modification of its global state, e.g.:

```
def call_foo():
    import foo
    foo_globals = foo.__dict__.copy()  # shallow copy, be careful!
    foo_globals["a"] += 1
    print(foo_globals["a"])
```

Otherwise you'll have to unload your module every time before you load it (and this can have a lot of undesired consequences, thus very **not recommended**), e.g.:

```
import sys

def call_foo():
    sys.modules.pop("foo", None)
    import foo
    foo.a += 1
    print(foo.a)
```

Comment: While this is technically possible, one should point out that the question mildly implies that the author does not know what kind of trouble he's about to get into. The whole "`a` in `foo` should be a global of that module, except it should not be a global of that module" is most likely misdirected.

Comment: @user2722968 - Absolutely, but there is the _"burn to learn"_ approach to learning... Ordinarily, what the OP is attempting to do is why there is OOP in Python in the first place, but that's a lesson for another day ;)